# Is there a more pythonic way to return instantiated classes on demand?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wondered if there was a more Pythonic way of doing this.
I have a bunch of dataclasses that havce attributes that I have set already, however, I won't always need each one, or, I may need to re-use them. At the moment they are all being instantiated and set to variables then imported when needed. I feel like that there must be a better way to do this.

For example, this is what I have now

The main class - truncated, it has methods etc too.

```
@dataclass
class Raster():
    name: str
    s3_path: str
    file_name: str
```

Then below I have this.

```
land = Raster(s3_path=xxxx,file_name=xxx)
sea = Raster(s3_path=xxxx,file_name=xxx)
```

Would it make more sense to have

```
def getLand():
    return Raster(s3_path=xxxx,file_name=xxx)
```

It all feels a little clunky. Within the class I have used the @cache decorator too so that when I call land.raw it loads the data the first time and then all other times it just returns from cache.

Comment: Having a "factory function" is quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

Such functions, acting as alternative constructors, are generally defined as class methods.

```
@dataclass
class Raster:
    name: str
    s3_path: str
    file_name: str

    @classmethod
    def make_land(cls):
        return cls(s3_path=xxxx, filename=xxx)


land = Raster.make_land()
sea = Raster.make_land()
```

The name used is mostly a matter of opinion and personal preference, but anything with `get` in the name suggests access to portion of an *existing* object, rather than something that *creates* a new object.